# Alternative to creating views in SQL read only database

Tags: mysql

I have some longish queries that creates views to simplify the queries a lot but the underlying DB I'm reading from has been changed to read-only. The views, of course, are no longer created, but I am dreading the huge refactor and the way these select statements are going to look without it. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Be aware that queries against views in MySQL cannot access their underlying indexes, rendering their utility doubtful

Comment: In clear RO database you may use once-created static tables instead of views.

Comment: I can't think of anything unless you're accessing it through another language like [tag:c-sharp], [tag:python] etc. At worst you should be able to generate your 'subqueries' through those.

Comment: Isn't refactoring just case of changing `SELECT stuff FROM my_view` to `SELECT stuff FROM (select_query_used_to_create_my_view) x` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on MySQL 8, you could get away with only a little refactoring by using CTEs, e.g. you can do something like

```
with tmp_a as (select id from table_a), 
     tmp_b as (select id from tmp_a)
select * from tmp_a a join tmp_b b on a.id = b.id
```

This would allow you to keep your basic code structure without much effort and as descriptive as your current code.

Before CTEs, you can just copy&paste the code of your views to wherever you use your views. MySQL actually does exactly the same when it runs your query, but if you use your views several times or heavily nested, it might not look as clean as CTEs. But the refactoring is still just limited to copy&paste.

To keep closer to your current situation with actual views, and maybe the least amount of refactoring, you could replace your views with temporary tables, which are allowed on read-only databases:

```
create view tmp_a as select id from table_a
```

becomes

```
create temporary table tmp_a as select id from table_a
```

This has the restriction though that you cannot use such a temporary table several times in a query (e.g. in a `from`/`join`), so you may have to check if this can happen, in which case you may have to create the temporary table several times (which may increase your memory requirements). Otherwise, you can use those almost like your views, with the exception that the temporary tables are only accessable in the session that created them, and will vanish with the session.

If you are on a readonly slave (and not a static database), you may also have to make sure that you are in a transaction if you use several base tables (e.g. not generate "view2" just from "view1"). In contrast to a single query based on views (which are merged into one big query), the temporary tables might otherwise represent different times.

Another alternative to get actual views, although this definitely has the smell of a workaround, could be to add a non-readonly dummy database on the server where you create the views and access the other database, e.g.

```
create view tmp_a as select id from ro_db.table_a
```

You'll need to adjust your queries to refer to the correct database, and of course have to setup the database and permissions.

Comment: Wouldn't you be unable to access temporary table more than once in the same session still? If the OP accesses the same views more than once, I think there can be a problem.